# Item values in list iterator not updating

Tags: python, image, python-3.x, scope, iterator

**I have some code that loops through `properties` of logos** and those properties are turned into the logos themselves.

The problem is, I have an "AntiAliasing / SuperSampling" feature that checks if `properties["antialias"] == True`.

If AA is enabled, it temporarily overrides some of the sizing properties to three times the size, renders, and then downscales to the original (by dividing by three).

**Here's the short part of code that matters:**

```
if properties["antialias"]:
    properties["font_size"] *= 3
    properties["base_size"] = (properties["base_size"][0] * 3,
                               properties["base_size"][1] * 3)
    properties["padding"] = (properties["padding"][0] * 3,
                             properties["padding"][1] * 3)
```

There you can see where `font_size`, `(tuple) base_size` and `(tuple) padding` are all multiplied by three. That's all the sizing information in the properties that's been loaded.

So after that happens, the image is generated by PIL (Pillow) and **then it's downsized by the following:**

```
if properties["antialias"]:
    logo_image = logo_image.resize((round(logo_image.width  / 3),
                                    round(logo_image.height / 3)), Image.ANTIALIAS)
```

**The problem with this is, the first image works fine. Then, the other images that are generated by that loop are all growing, exponentially by a *power* of three. That is clearly *not*  exponent code.**

The conclusion that I reached is that each "properties" (the item being used each loop) dictionary that is called is not changing (perhaps only the modified values) and instead repeatedly multiplying by three.

(Basically I think the changed values are staying the same through each loop.)

This is the loop as you would expect:

```
for properties in logo_list:
```

**Here is the full code if you need to read it.** It calls from outer scope variables, and other functions, but I don't expect that to matter for this question.

```
for properties in logo_list:
    if weight in properties["weights"]:
        logo_name = "".join([region["text"] for region in properties["regions"]])
        logo_file = logo_name + "-" + file[:-4] + "." + properties["type"].lower()
        out_dir = os.path.join("out", logo_name)

        try:
            os.makedirs(out_dir)
        except FileExistsError:
            pass

        if properties["antialias"]:
            properties["font_size"] *= 3
            properties["base_size"] = (properties["base_size"][0] * 3,
                                       properties["base_size"][1] * 3)
            properties["padding"] = (properties["padding"][0] * 3,
                                     properties["padding"][1] * 3)

        logo_image = generate(properties, font_path)

        if properties["shrink"]:
            logo_image = logo_image.crop(logo_image.getbbox())

        if properties["padding"]:
            logo_image = padding(properties, logo_image)

        if properties["antialias"]:
            logo_image = logo_image.resize((round(logo_image.width  / 3),
                                            round(logo_image.height / 3)), Image.ANTIALIAS)

        if properties["background"]:
            logo_image = background(properties, logo_image)

        logo_image.save(os.path.join(out_dir, logo_file), properties["type"])
```

[**Since people asked, here is the *absolute full*  code.**](https://gist.github.com/spikespaz/6e9913125842b3e2e638662f26698b7e)

Comment: What does your `generate()` function do? Can we see that? It may help since that is what seems to create the image you actually work with during the code for resizing that gives you an issue.

Comment: Added to the bottom. All files are there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDITED: You are looping over files, and then for each file, looping over logo_list.  Then you modify the items of logo_list.  So the second file will use logo_list with its modified items.  This means you multiply by three each time around, which produces the exponential growth.

Comment: `logo_list` is just [this](https://gist.github.com/spikespaz/6e9913125842b3e2e638662f26698b7e) in JSON format.

Comment: I can't explain it then.  Include the entire program, maybe something else will become apparent.

Comment: I added the code to [the same gist](https://gist.github.com/spikespaz/6e9913125842b3e2e638662f26698b7e).

Comment: @NedBatchelder is right. You should add `logo_list = load(open("settings.json"))` just above the loop where you iterate over it, `for properties in logo_list:`, so that you call it fresh for each file.

Comment: Thanks. What I changed it to was this:
`for properties in load(open("settings.json")):`
I didn't realize that `properties` would be mutable outside of that instance.
Is there a better way to do that without changing too much to prevent reloading the file every iteration? And if you have a neat trick to do so, please add it to the answer.